# How to build an RNN model with a large extra loop from its output to its next input?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I am aiming to build a RNN in Keras/TensorFlow that consists of layers of recurrent units (GRU, LSTM, etc.) as well as a loop from the bottom of the network to the top, to add an attention mechanism or special memory types. I am not familiar with symbolic loops, so first I tried to build an unrolled model along these lines:

[image: recurrent network and unrolling]

As far as I see, what I would need to do this is an RNN layer with two input tensors and two output tensors as I would need to "route" the internal input/output of the RNN layers (green) myself to unroll these connections at the same time as the big loop (blue).

I can handle implementing the unrolled big loop with the concat layer and a custom splitting layer ( https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/890 ), but with the RNN layers I ran into a problem as I don't seem to be able to simulate them using more primitive layers (Dense, Activation, etc.). Before reimplementing them including the backprop step in a way that I can specify separate tensors as their external input and internal input, is there a better way to do this, possibly by somehow reusing existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project at https://github.com/csirmaz/superloop allows implementing RNNs with such a big loop. It seems to use its own implementation of RNN layers to get two inputs and two outputs.